# How to combine multiple JSON files into a single file in R

Tags: json, r

i have three JSON files

- `json1` contains `[[1,5],[5,7],[8,10]]`
- `json2` contains `[[5,6],[4,5],[5,8]]`
- `json3` contains `[[4,7],[3,4],[4,8]]`

I want to merge them into one single file `jsonmerge`:

```
  [[[1,5],[5,7],[8,10]],[[5,6],[4,5],[5,8]],[[4,7],[3,4],[4,8]]]
```

I tried concatenate but it gave results in this format

```
   [[5,6],[4,5],[5,8]],
   [[5,6],[4,5],[5,8]],
   [[4,7],[3,4],[4,8]]
```

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `rjson` package, then you need to concatenate them into a list:

```
library(rjson)
json1 <- fromJSON(file = "json1")
json2 <- fromJSON(file = "json2")
json3 <- fromJSON(file = "json3")
jsonl <- list(json1, json2, json3)
jsonc <- toJSON(jsonc)
jsonc
[1] "[[[1,5],[5,7],[8,10]],[[5,6],[4,5],[5,8]],[[4,7],[3,4],[4,8]]]"
write(jsonc, file = "jsonc")
```

If you have many files, you can put them in a vector and use `lapply` to save some typing:

```
files <- c("json1", "json2", "json3")
jsonl <- lapply(files, function(f) fromJSON(file = f))
jsonc <- toJSON(jsonl)
write(jsonc, file = "jsonc")
```