# Merge three json lists in R

Tags: r, json

I have created three different json objects with R. They look like (I put a small subset of each):

JSON 1:

```
[
 {
  "id": "user_F_1",
  "group": {
    "age": "32"
  },
  "activity": {
    "sport": "football"
  },
  "scores": {
    "2016": "85",
    "2017": "87"
   }
 },
 {
   "id": "user_F_2",
   "group": {
     "age": "32"
   },
   "activity": {
     "sport": "hockey"
   },
   "scores": {
     "2016": "62",
     "2017": "75"
   }
 }
]
```

JSON 2:

```
[
 {
  "id": "user_H_1",
  "gender": "male",
  "region": {
    "country": "Finland"
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_H_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "region": {
    "country": "Greece"
  }
 }
]
```

JSON 3:

```
[  
 {
  "id": "user_Z_1",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "35",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Europe",
    "country": "France",
    "teamgroup": 3
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_Z_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "46",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "China",
    "teamgroup": 17
  }
 }
]
```

I need to merge them into one single json object. 
Following what was suggested in this [question/27524122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524122/how-to-combine-multiple-json-files-into-a-single-file-in-r) I tried to do:

```
jsonl <- list(fromJSON(json1), fromJSON(json2), fromJSON(json3))
jsonc <- toJSON(jsonl, pretty=TRUE)
```

But it concatenates the three of them, not merge. I mean, it returns:

```
[
 {
  "id": "user_F_1",
  "group": {
    "age": "32"
  },
  "activity": {
    "sport": "football"
  },
  "scores": {
    "2016": "85",
    "2017": "87"
   }
 },
 {
   "id": "user_F_2",
   "group": {
     "age": "32"
   },
   "activity": {
     "sport": "hockey"
   },
   "scores": {
     "2016": "62",
     "2017": "75"
   }
 }
],
[
 {
  "id": "user_H_1",
  "gender": "male",
  "region": {
    "country": "Finland"
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_H_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "region": {
    "country": "Greece"
  }
 }
],
[  
 {
  "id": "user_Z_1",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "35",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Europe",
    "country": "France",
    "teamgroup": 3
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_Z_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "46",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "China",
    "teamgroup": 17
  }
 }
]
```

and I need:

```
[
 {
  "id": "user_F_1",
  "group": {
    "age": "32"
  },
  "activity": {
    "sport": "football"
  },
  "scores": {
    "2016": "85",
    "2017": "87"
   }
 },
 {
   "id": "user_F_2",
   "group": {
     "age": "32"
   },
   "activity": {
     "sport": "hockey"
   },
   "scores": {
     "2016": "62",
     "2017": "75"
   }
 },
 {
  "id": "user_H_1",
  "gender": "male",
  "region": {
    "country": "Finland"
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_H_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "region": {
    "country": "Greece"
  }
 },  
 {
  "id": "user_Z_1",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "35",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Europe",
    "country": "France",
    "teamgroup": 3
  }
},
{
  "id": "user_Z_2",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": "46",
  "data": {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "China",
    "teamgroup": 17
  }
 }
]
```

i.e. without the square brackets between the different jsons. All the elements inside one block of square brackets: `[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]`.

I also tried the `paste0` option in this [question/47983058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376058/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-in-r-by-keeping-the-json-structure), but it's not working either.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Jet answer, I solved my problem by removing the brackets first, then concatenating all the jsons, and finally adding brackets again at the beginning and at the end of the resulting json:

```
cat("[",gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json1), ",", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json2), ",", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json3),"]" )
```

If you want to write this in a json file, then:

```
fileConn<-file("Output.json")
writeLines(paste0("[", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json1), ",", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json2), ",", gsub("\\[|\\]", "",json3),"]"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `fromJSON` returns a list. To concatenate lists, you should use the `c` function.

```
json_all <- c(fromJSON(json1), fromJSON(json2), fromJSON(json3))
jsonc <- toJSON(json_all, pretty=TRUE)
```

---

Example :

```
json1 <- '
[
{
  "id": "user_H_1",
  "gender": "male"
}
]' 

json2 <- '
[
{
  "id": "user_H_1e",
  "gender": "female"
},
{
  "id": "user_H_2e",
  "age": "62"
}
]'
```

Merging :

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(c(fromJSON(json1), fromJSON(json2)), pretty=TRUE)
```

Output :

```
{
  "id": ["user_H_1"],
  "gender": ["male"],
  "id.1": ["user_H_1e", "user_H_2e"],
  "gender.1": ["female", null],
  "age": [null, "62"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, as you show in your example, this doesn't return what I need to have as output. In your solution every element now is a list... I need exactly the same json structure for each json object, and just merge them one below the other inside one square bracket as I said above `[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]`

Comment: Then there mey be no point using json handling functions. You may just strip `[` & `]` brackets at the start and end of the strings, and concatenate them like normal strings using `paste0`

Comment: Ok. Well, I followed your advice and got something that works. I posted the answer below. Thanks again.